# Initializing state in React.js with objects: Is it better to initialize with an empty object or with an object in the same shape as it will be set?

Tags: reactjs

I've been digging around and I'm just trying to figure out best practice with no luck finding anything. I understand that in either case the end result will be the same but I'm trying to think of this from a readability perspective for other developers working on the same application .

For example this is the shape that this particular state will be:

```js
{
  id: '',
  value: {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: [],
  }
}
```

My thought is to do this:

```js
// initial state
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
  id: '',
  value: {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: [],
  }
})

...

// setting state after some data comes in
setSomeState({
  id: 'someId',
  value: {
    arr1: [...someData],
    arr2: [...someData],
  }
})
```

I won't ever need to use the initially set object for anything but I think this would still be beneficial to another developer coming into the file because they'll have a clear idea of what the state looks like from the start. The downside is that this creates an otherwise useless object which is slower, I'm guessing, so it would be better to just initialize this state as an empty object.

Pretty minor but something I'm curious about. What do we think?

Comment: Good question. I always set the initial state to ```null``` until it is actually defined. But I use typescript, so the type of the state is very explicit: ```const [foo, setFoo] = useState<FooInterface | null>(null);```. I don't think there would be any performance impacts if you do that, but in my opinion it is not necessary.

Comment: It's not "slower" in any meaningful way, and the microseconds in object creation time pales in comparison to making somebody figure out what something should look like later. In any case it'd still boil down to opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On small and easy projects I initialize with null for objects, empty strings for later strings and so on so I just know all values I'll need in the future are not undefined. Undefined for me means I dont even defined the variable. But this is personal...

If you are going for bigger projects or working with other developers you may use TypeScript. This is exactly what you are trying to do here but you'll get much more like syntax highlighting.